# Handling Dependency 4XX in REST

Tags: rest, http

I am wondering what would be the appropriate error code to bubble upto my clients when I get 4XX from my dependencies. Say for example, one of my downstream services returns to me a 401 code. This means my own server was not authorised for this request. How should I bubble this information to my clients? Would 424 be the appropriate code to bubble up? I read that it was added to HTTP as an extension, so is it recommended to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status codes from extensions can be used when properly registered and sufficiently defined.

That said, a 4xx seems to be incorrect here. If your server is not configured properly to access a back end, that's a server error, thus a 5xx.

Comment: What if say I get a 409 conflict while calling some operation on a resource downstream?

Comment: It's an error condition in your server, no? So, no, it should be a 5xx. There's nothing the client can do about it, right?